# How to get all rows for specific column from .csv file

Tags: c#, .net, console-application

In my project, I have a .csv file with many columns.
I need to extract all rows for only first column. I've managed to read all lines, but got stuck on how to extract rows from first column to another .csv file.

```cs
string filePath = @"C:\Users\BP185150\Desktop\OTC.csv";
            
string[] OTC_Output = File.ReadAllLines(@"C:\Users\BP185150\Desktop\OTC.csv");

foreach (string line in OTC_Output)
{
     Console.WriteLine(line);
     Console.Read();
}
Console.ReadLine();
```

Comment: That's one downside of csv. You need to parse rows. i.e. You read the whole row, then filter. CSV libs can relieve some of the pain, though.

Answer (score 1):

Depending on what seperator your csv is using you can use the `string.split()` function.

e.g.

```
string firstItem = line.Split(',')[0];
Console.WriteLine(firstItem);
```

Adding them to a collection:

```cs
ICollection<string> firstItems = new List<string>();
string[] OTC_Output = File.ReadAllLines(@"C:\Users\BP185150\Desktop\OTC.csv");

foreach (string line in OTC_Output)
{
    firstItems.Add(line.Split(',')[0]);
}
```

Comment: that work's, but what confuses me is that in console I'm getting two results at the same time, e.g:
1451320
1309078 ||

1237603
1250721 ||

1237603
1250721

etc. 
Can't figure out why is that happening since there are only "," which have been split

Answer (score 1):

Well if you want to use File.ReadAllLines, the best way to get the first column is to split the line with a delimiter that your csv is using. Then just add the first item of every line to a collection.

```
var column = OTC_Output.Select(line => line.Split(';').First()).ToList();
```

Answer (score 1):

In lineItems, you'll have all the columns splitted:

```
var lineItems = line.Split(";").ToArray();
```

Then, parse the value only for the first of them:

```
lineItems.GetValue(0).ToString();
```